# Two Bindings for the same contract

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I have a contract for which i have an basicHttpBinding.

```
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:49654/BookShopService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BookShop.IBookShopService">
            </endpoint>
```

I want to add another endpoint with wsHttpBinding, for the same binding.
What are the steps I have to take? What would be the resulting address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another endpoint with a different address, it should look like this:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:49654/BookShopService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="BookShop.IBookShopService">
</endpoint>
<endpoint address="http://localhost:49654/BookShopServiceWS" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="BookShop.IBookShopService">
</endpoint>
```

There is a primer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in IIS, then you shouldn't supply a fully qualified address - the address will be determined by IIS and so supply one can cause deployment problems.  So, using Greg Sansom's answer as a foundation, I'd suggest

```
<endpoint address="" 
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    contract="BookShop.IBookShopService" /> 
<endpoint address="ws" 
    binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    contract="BookShop.IBookShopService" />
```

where `ws` is a relative addresses to the service location.

e.g.

- http://localhost:49654/BookShopService.svc - the basicHttp endpoint
- http://localhost:49654/BookShopService.svc/ws - the wsHttp endpoint